# Upload from IOS picture to .net app: Rotate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload, image

I have below code for uploading and resize pictures from IOS Devices to my .net application. Users use to take picture in portrait orientation and then all pictures show up in my app with wrong rotation. Any suggestion how to fix this?

```
            string fileName = Server.HtmlEncode(FileUploadFormbilde.FileName);
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            System.Drawing.Image image_file = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUploadFormbilde.PostedFile.InputStream);
            int image_height = image_file.Height;
            int image_width = image_file.Width;
            int max_height = 300;
            int max_width = 300;

            image_height = (image_height * max_width) / image_width;
            image_width = max_width;

            if (image_height > max_height)
            {
                image_width = (image_width * max_height) / image_height;
                image_height = max_height;
            }

            Bitmap bitmap_file = new Bitmap(image_file, image_width, image_height);
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            bitmap_file.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            stream.Position = 0;

            byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length + 1];
            stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Answer (score 31):

Here you go my friend:

```
Image originalImage = Image.FromStream(data);

 if (originalImage.PropertyIdList.Contains(0x0112))
        {
            int rotationValue = originalImage.GetPropertyItem(0x0112).Value[0];
            switch (rotationValue)
            {
                case 1: // landscape, do nothing
                    break;

                case 8: // rotated 90 right
                    // de-rotate:
                    originalImage.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType: RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                    break;

                case 3: // bottoms up
                    originalImage.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType: RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                    break;

                case 6: // rotated 90 left
                    originalImage.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType: RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: FYI, to use `PropertyIdList.Contains()` you must include `using System.Linq`.

Comment: You saved my behind here bud!

Comment: Some values are missing, this property can contain any value from 1 to 8 : http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html

Comment: My images appear squashed.  Is anyone else experiencing that?

Answer (score 1):

You must read the image's Orientation value from the EXIF data in the [Image.PropertyItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.propertyitems.aspx) collection, and rotate it accordingly.

Comment: Any Code Example? I can't find out how to successfully implement this in my code.

Comment: Sorry. You're already on the right Image object, I gave you a link to read. I strongly believe it is important to learn by doing, not by copy-pasting code. 
(Not that there are hundreds of code samples out there.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better solution answer posted  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38460026/3038042)  He  wrote a simple helper class that does all that:

[you can check the full source code here.](http://www.ryadel.com/en/change-image-orientation-iphone-andor-android-phone-pics-net-c/)

```
    private System.Drawing.Image ResizeAndDraw(System.Drawing.Image objTempImage)
        {
          // call image helper to fix the orientation issue 
            var temp = ImageHelper.RotateImageByExifOrientationData(objTempImage, true);
            Size objSize = new Size(150, 200);
            Bitmap objBmp;
            objBmp = new Bitmap(objSize.Width, objSize.Height);

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(objBmp);
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, thumbSize.Width, thumbSize.Height);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,150,200);
            //g.DrawImage(objTempImage, rect, 0, 0, objTempImage.Width, objTempImage.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            g.DrawImage(objTempImage, rect);
            return objBmp;
        }


using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;

public static class ImageHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Rotate the given image file according to Exif Orientation data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceFilePath">path of source file</param>
    /// <param name="targetFilePath">path of target file</param>
    /// <param name="targetFormat">target format</param>
    /// <param name="updateExifData">set it to TRUE to update image Exif data after rotation (default is TRUE)</param>
    /// <returns>The RotateFlipType value corresponding to the applied rotation. If no rotation occurred, RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone will be returned.</returns>
    public static RotateFlipType RotateImageByExifOrientationData(string sourceFilePath, string targetFilePath, ImageFormat targetFormat, bool updateExifData = true)
    {
        // Rotate the image according to EXIF data
        var bmp = new Bitmap(sourceFilePath);
        RotateFlipType fType = RotateImageByExifOrientationData(bmp, updateExifData);
        if (fType != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone)
        {
            bmp.Save(targetFilePath, targetFormat);
        }
        return fType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rotate the given bitmap according to Exif Orientation data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="img">source image</param>
    /// <param name="updateExifData">set it to TRUE to update image Exif data after rotation (default is TRUE)</param>
    /// <returns>The RotateFlipType value corresponding to the applied rotation. If no rotation occurred, RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone will be returned.</returns>
    public static RotateFlipType RotateImageByExifOrientationData(Image img, bool updateExifData = true)
    {
        int orientationId = 0x0112;
        var fType = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;
        if (img.PropertyIdList.Contains(orientationId))
        {
            var pItem = img.GetPropertyItem(orientationId);
            fType = GetRotateFlipTypeByExifOrientationData(pItem.Value[0]);
            if (fType != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone)
            {
                img.RotateFlip(fType);
                // Remove Exif orientation tag (if requested)
                if (updateExifData) img.RemovePropertyItem(orientationId);
            }
        }
        return fType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the proper System.Drawing.RotateFlipType according to given orientation EXIF metadata
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orientation">Exif "Orientation"</param>
    /// <returns>the corresponding System.Drawing.RotateFlipType enum value</returns>
    public static RotateFlipType GetRotateFlipTypeByExifOrientationData(int orientation)
    {
        switch (orientation)
        {
            case 1:
            default:
                return RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;
            case 2:
                return RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX;
            case 3:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone;
            case 4:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX;
            case 5:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX;
            case 6:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone;
            case 7:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX;
            case 8:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone;
        }
    }
}
```