# Uploading picture from mobile is showing up sideways

Tags: c#

I have an option to upload an image

```
<input class="images" type="file" id="item" name="Images" />
```

it then gets saved to my project like this

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
                Images.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + g + ".jpg"));
                fileNames = g.ToString() + ".jpg";
```

for some reason when someone uploads a picture to the site from mobile it shows up sideways?

Comment: Take a look at this answer on exif orientation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835064/get-image-orientation-and-rotate-as-per-orientation

Comment: You'll need to examine the image metadata (exif) then rotate based on one of the eight orientations. This can be done in javascript before upload or on the server.

Answer (score 8):

You can look at the metadata of the file to see which way it is rotated.

Specifically, pull the image in as a .NET Image type, then call img.GetPropertyItem(&H112).Value(0).

That will return an integer, which represents the "rotation value" of the image.

```
1 = Landscape
3 = Upside-down
6 = Rotated 90 degrees left
8 = Rotated 90 degrees right
```

Once you know that, you can then rotate the image using the img.RotateFlip method.

Below is a class I wrote to solve very similar problems.

The relevant code is in the RotateImage method.

*Note: this was in VB.NET and I ran it through the telerik code converter, so my apologies for any weird syntax*

```
//get the image from the file they gave us, resize it, and rotate it if needed
    OnlineImage onlineImageHelper = new OnlineImage(Context.Request.Files(0).InputStream);
    byte[] pictureLarger = onlineImageHelper.StraightenedThumbnail(new Size(180, 180));
    byte[] pictureSmaller = onlineImageHelper.StraightenedThumbnail(new Size(80, 80));

using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

public class OnlineImage
{
    public OnlineImage()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public OnlineImage(Stream imageStream)
    {
        _ImageFromUser = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
        RotateImage();
    }

    private Image _ImageFromUser;
    private Image _RotatedImage;
    private Image _ResizedAndRotatedImage;

    private void RotateImage()
    {
        if (_RotatedImage == null && _ImageFromUser != null && _ImageFromUser.PropertyIdList != null && _ImageFromUser.PropertyIdList.Contains(0x112)) {
            int rotationValue = _ImageFromUser.GetPropertyItem(0x112).Value(0);
            switch (rotationValue) {
                case 1:
                    // landscape, do nothing
                    break;
                case 8:
                    // rotated 90 right
                    // de-rotate:
                    _ImageFromUser.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType: RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // bottoms up
                    _ImageFromUser.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType: RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    // rotated 90 left
                    _ImageFromUser.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType: RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                    break;
            }
            _RotatedImage = _ImageFromUser;
        }
    }

    private void ResizeImage(Size size, bool preserveAspectRatio = true)
    {
        int newWidth = 0;
        int newHeight = 0;
        if (preserveAspectRatio) {
            int originalWidth = _ImageFromUser.Width;
            int originalHeight = _ImageFromUser.Height;
            float percentWidth = Convert.ToSingle(size.Width) / Convert.ToSingle(originalWidth);
            float percentHeight = Convert.ToSingle(size.Height) / Convert.ToSingle(originalHeight);
            float percent = percentHeight < percentWidth ? percentHeight : percentWidth;
            newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(originalWidth * percent);
            newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(originalHeight * percent);
        } else {
            newWidth = size.Width;
            newHeight = size.Height;
        }

        _ResizedAndRotatedImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

        using (Graphics graphicsHandle = Graphics.FromImage(_ResizedAndRotatedImage)) {
            graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphicsHandle.DrawImage(_ImageFromUser, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        }
    }

    public byte[] StraightenedThumbnail(Size resizedDimensions)
    {
        byte[] result = null;
        MemoryStream msPicture = new MemoryStream();
        ResizeImage(resizedDimensions);
        if (_ResizedAndRotatedImage != null) {
            _ResizedAndRotatedImage.Save(msPicture, ImageFormat.Png);
            result = msPicture.ToArray();
            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Images is a HttpPostedFileBase isn't that a .NET Image type? Why does it not know what .GetPropertyItem is?

Comment: When I said ".net image type", I was referring to the type "System.Drawing.Image"

Comment: hmm I am trying. Shouldn't this work? Images.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + g + ".jpg")); fileNames = g.ToString() + ".jpg"; Image img = Image.FromFile(fileNames); What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found this helpful blog post: https://www.cyotek.com/blog/handling-the-orientation-exif-tag-in-images-using-csharp
One point mentioned in this post is to remove the EXIF Orientation tag after correctly rotating the image before saving it again