# how to determine jpg image orientation

Tags: powershell

Need to get height and width of image files in shell script.

I have a script that returns the correct image size, however the height and width don't always correlate to the correct orientation (portrait or landscape).  Is there an attribute I can check to determine whether to use h x W or W x H ?

```
$imgloc = 'c:\pics'
$folder = 'pics'
Set-Location -Path $imgloc

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $imgloc
$icnt = 0
foreach ($file in $files) {
    if ($file.Extension -ne ".jpg") { continue }
    $icnt++
   $hfile = (get-item $file)
    $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($hfile);
    $ih= $img.Size.Height
    $iw= $img.Size.width
    $imgsize = "$iw"+"x"+"$ih"

    $imgsize
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835064/get-image-orientation-and-rotate-as-per-orientation There is a `PropertyTagOrientation`.

Comment: This solution looks like it will work, however I was unable to get it to work in my script.  Using the below syntax, I am getting this error : Exception calling "GetPropertyItem" with "1" argument(s): "Property cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like below to get all the properties you seem to need from the jpg file and act upon the returned value `Orientation`

```
$imgloc = 'D:\'           #'# dummy comment to restore syntax highlighting in SO

# the various System.Photo.Orientation values
# See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-photo-orientation
#      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-constant-property-item-descriptions#propertytagorientation
$orientation = 'Unknown', 'Normal', 'FlipHorizontal', 'Rotate180', 'FlipVertical', 'Transpose', 'Rotate270', 'Transverse', 'Rotate90'

Get-ChildItem -Path $imgloc -Filter '*.jpg' | ForEach-Object {
    $img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($_.FullName)
    # return the properties
    $value = $img.GetPropertyItem(274).Value[0]
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Path'        = $_.FullName
        'Width'       = $img.Size.width
        'Height'      = $img.Size.Height
        'Orientation' = $orientation[$value]
    }
}
```

This would return as example

> ```
> Path         Width Height Orientation
> ----         ----- ------ -----------
> D:\test.jpg   2592   1456 Normal     
> D:\test2.jpg  2336   4160 Normal     
> D:\test3.jpg  2560   1920 Rotate270
> ```

and if `Orientation` is either `Rotate270` or `Rotate90` you can swap the values for width and height.

**Edit**

As [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) commented, the orientation values are also declared in the `[System.Drawing.RotateFlipType]` enum class like this:

```
Name               Value
----               -----
Rotate180FlipXY        0
RotateNoneFlipNone     0
Rotate90FlipNone       1
Rotate270FlipXY        1
Rotate180FlipNone      2
RotateNoneFlipXY       2
Rotate270FlipNone      3
Rotate90FlipXY         3
RotateNoneFlipX        4
Rotate180FlipY         4
Rotate90FlipX          5
Rotate270FlipY         5
Rotate180FlipX         6
RotateNoneFlipY        6
Rotate270FlipX         7
Rotate90FlipY          7
```

with values ranging from 0 to 7 and none of them distinct, whereas the values you get using `$img.GetPropertyItem(274).Value[0]` range from 1 to 8 and coincide with the values for [System.Photo.Orientation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-photo-orientation)

Comment: [`$value = $img.GetPropertyItem( 274).Value[0]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-constant-property-item-descriptions#propertytagorientation) and `$orientation` values are declared in the `[System.Drawing.RotateFlipType]` enum class.

Comment: @JosefZ Please see my edit. IMO the values you retrieve agree more with the `[System.Photo.Orientation]` values which results in clearer descriptive names, hence the lookup array. I did change the way the value is read with your cleaner suggestion `$value = $img.GetPropertyItem(274).Value[0]` though. Thanks for that.

Comment: I can't absorb _`GDI+`_ versus _`.Net`_ discrepancies… And now I'm totally confused with  _Windows Property System_ [grin]…