# Pasting images into RichTextBox using clipboard. Some of them are rotating 90 degrees. Need to detect/correct

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a program using VB.Net and am pasting images (JPG) into a rich text box.  The relevant piece of code is as follows:

```
For Each Picture As String In ShopAndCraftItem.FileList
   
    Dim img As Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Directory_Server.ShopAndCraftsPictureFilePath & "\" & Picture)
    Clipboard.SetImage(img)
    Me.rtfReport.AppendText(m_Tab_2)
    Me.rtfReport.Paste()
    Me.rtfReport.AppendText(vbCrLf)

    Me.rtfReport.Font = SC_BoldFont
    Me.rtfReport.AppendText(m_Tab_1 & "Picture".PadRight(ReportPad, ".") & Picture & vbCrLf)

Next`
```

ShopAndCraftItem.FileList is a class I created that holds categories of shop and craft items (i.e. lawn mower, radial saw, sewing machine) and, if I have entered it, several bits of information about each category including, if I have linked them, a list of file names in a specific directory.  My program spins through the list of categories.  If a category has information about an item, it reports that.  If it has a list of associated files, it spins through the list and pastes them into the rich textbox followed by the safe name of that file.  Directory_Server is a class I created to abstract a lot of directory/file related things specific to my program.   rtfReport is a standard RichTextBox control from the VB toolbox.

I'm using Visual Studio version 17.8.1.

The code works as desired except that some of the images are being rotated 90 degrees when pasted.  They are NOT rotated on the disk and it does not happen for most of the pictures.  The pictures all come from a small digital camera.  I'm not doing anything special or different with the pictures or in my code.  I believe I can figure out HOW to rotate them appropriately if I can determine how to identify when it has occurred.  Even better would be a case where they did not rotate at all.  If there is something I'm doing wrong (or could do better), I have not been able to figure it out.  I have done a lot of research and cannot find anything helpful.  Can anyone help me resolve this?

Thank you!
e.g.bell

I have searched for how to rotate the images.  I have found what I believe I need to do that but I would prefer to prevent the rotation in the first place. What I found must be done manually. I want to prevent the problem or recognize it and correct it programmatically.  I don't know what to search for to identify the problem, or recognize it once it has occurred. I appreciate any help offered.

Comment: Although it uses C#, maybe [Get Image Orientation and rotate as per orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835064/get-image-orientation-and-rotate-as-per-orientation) has the information you need to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This response was effective.  Thank you.  I had continued to research but had only begun to look into propertyitems. It was daunting.  I work in VB but C# is not a difficult conversion.  I added the following code to my program:

```
  Private Sub GetImageProperties(ByRef img As System.Drawing.Image)

  Dim Rotate As Integer = 0
  For Each prop In img.PropertyItems

     If prop.Id = 274 OrElse prop.Id = 5029 Then
        Select Case prop.Value(0)
           Case 6 : Rotate = 90
              img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone)

           Case 8 : Rotate = -90
              img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)

           Case 3 : Rotate = 180

        End Select

        prop.Value(0) = 1
     End If

  Next
```

End Sub

This was based on the C# snipped suggested.  'img' is passed into this by reference so that I could do any necessary rotation.  Only 90 degree rotations were necessasry.  The only direction offered is clockwise so I used 270 when a 90 degree counterclockwise was required.  I'm going to remove the ROTATE variable as it is a remnant of the original snippet but I did not need it.

The rotate methods offer a lot of nuances (x, xy, flip, etc) that I do not yet understand.  I'll pursue those on my own.  The upshot is that this got me more than I had dared to hope.  ***Thank you very much*** for such a quick effective solution.  I came here after a LOT of time wasted looking places that did not help and not even knowing about ones that would.