Image.GetThumbnailImage rotates the image when it was taken using a mobile phone
I have the following extension methods to create thumbnails from a photo in a .NET Core 8 web application:
public static class ImageExtensions
{
    public static Image ToThumbnail(this Image image, int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {
        return image.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    public static Image ToThumbnail(this string path, int newWidth, int newHeight, string newPath)
    {
        var image = Image.FromFile(path);
        var thumbnail = image.ToThumbnail(newWidth, newHeight);
        thumbnail.Save(newPath);
        return thumbnail;
    }
}

When I take a picture using my mobile phone and transmit it to the web application, original photo is stored the same way as it was taken, however, the thumbnail is saved totated 90 degrees clockwise.
The photo was taken in portrait orientation of my phone.
Why when I create the thumbnail using GetThumbnailImage method, photo get rotated? How can I fix this?
Thanks
Jaime

Docs say "If the Image contains an embedded thumbnail image, this method retrieves the embedded thumbnail and scales it to the requested size" - could that be it? It's not rotating it, the embedded thumbnail image has a different orientation?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835064/get-image-orientation-and-rotate-as-per-orientation#48347653
